# Set public DNS server on work PC, can no longer authenticate with domain controller

Tags: windows-7, windows, networking, dns, windows-domain

As in topic title, I have a domain account with admin privileges to the particular PC I use.

I'm an idiot, and when some addresses wouldn't resolve thought I'd try changing DNS server.

Obviously now everything is screwed - no network, and I can't authenticate with the domain at the admin prompt to edit the adaptor properties.

Is there any way of starting an elevated command prompt with runas and specifying a logon server/bypassing DNS? I have access to other PCs on the network here and know the IP of our logon server.

To my knowledge there are no local admin accounts on the box, and the default administrator account is disabled. The only thing I can think of is using a linux live USB with chntpw to enable the built-in admin account and correcting the problem with that.

Please send help.

Comment: Do you have access to another network adapter (a USB one, say)? That would inevitably use the automatic settings given by Windows as DNS is set at the individual adapter level, rather than system wide. As you  quite rightly state, if you have no other admin accounts then you'll need to enable one, with whatever means you have suggested.... WinPE/WinRM may also help. You could use the old `sethc.exe` switch with `cmd.exe` hack to get a SYSTEM account CMD window at the Windows logon screen using the Sticky Keys exploit.

Comment: Sadly I do not, but this is a wonderful idea! Would a USB to ethernet adapter do the trick? I think yes, but want to make sure before purchasing.

(Actually, all the PCs here _do_ have wireless adaptors - so although one is not provided by work I could potentially start an ad-hoc network on another and then connect to it...)

Comment: Depends whether the OS identifies the drivers without needing UAC. if UAC kicks in then, again, you'll need to pr3ovide admin credentials. To guarantee admin credentials you'll need to enable a local admin account. The `sethc.exe` hack will need access to the Windows filesystem through either the likes of a Linux live CD or a Windows WinPE environment. Not much more you can do... this is one way of screwing a machine... thank god you haven't got an encrypted drive.

Comment: If your GPO doesn't forbid password-storages, then you can simply unplug the ethernet-cable. By realising that the computer has no connected network, it will compare the password you enter with the password it stored locally.

By default the last 10 passwords are saved.